# Как подставить символы типа String в выражение?

Tags: java

Как подставить символы типа String в выражение.

```
 String s = "(";
 String p = "+";
 String so = ")";

 int i = 1;
 int j = 2;
 int res;

 // res = (1+2); Как мне получить такое выражение? 
 // может нужно использовать не String?
```

Comment: Если вам нужна строка, то просио объедените их, а если вычислить результат, то, пожалуй, нужен синтаксический анализатор

Comment: Да, мне нужен результат

Comment: Тогда пишите синтаксический анализатор или ищите готовый

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Создание строки выражения из данных***

- Для этого может воспользуемся экземляром класса `StringBuilder`

  ```
      final String s = "(";
      final String p = "+";
      final String so = ")";

      final int i = 1;
      final int j = 2;
      int res;

      // res = (1+2); Как мне получить такое выражение?
      // может нужно использовать не String?
      final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append(s).append(i).append(p).append(j).append(so);
  ```
- Далее понадобиться переменная для хранения строки выражения

  `// expressionString = (1+2)
   final String expressionString = sb.toString();`
- Далее воспользуемся возможностями Java SE 1.6

  ```
      final javax.script.ScriptEngineManager mgr = new javax.script.ScriptEngineManager();
      final javax.script.ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

      try {
          final Object resObj = engine.eval(expressionString);
          res = ((Integer)resObj).intValue();
          System.out.println(res);
      } catch (javax.script.ScriptException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
  }
  ```

**Полный код примера**:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "(";
        String p = "+";
        String so = ")";

        int i = 1;
        int j = 2;
        int res;

        // res = (1+2); Как мне получить такое выражение?
        // может нужно использовать не String?
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(s).append(i).append(p).append(j).append(so);


        final String expressionString = sb.toString();

        final javax.script.ScriptEngineManager mgr = new javax.script.ScriptEngineManager();
        final javax.script.ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

        try {
            final Object resObj = engine.eval(expressionString);
            res = ((Integer)resObj).intValue();
            System.out.println(res);
        } catch (javax.script.ScriptException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Множество задач можно решить кодом на JavaScript, например:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;


public class Test { 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
      ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
      ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
      try {
         Object result = engine.eval("1+2");
         System.out.println(result);
      } catch (ScriptException e) {}    
   }
}
```

Результат:

```
3
```

Что касается кода на java, насколько я знаю библиотека рефлексии не умеет выполнять не скомпилированный в байткод текст. Поэтому, если у программы во время выполнения есть доступ к javac, то вполне возможно вызвать компилятор из программы:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("запускаемая_программа");
```

Cкомпилировать код как отдельный класс и вызывать его предварительно подключив:

```
Class c = Class.forName("Test"); 
Object obj = c.newInstance();
```